# Change line spacing in nested nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize, line-spacing

I tried to change the line spacing in a node nested to another. I have tried to use `\linepsread` and `\baselineskip` but both doesn't work.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle,fill=blue,align=center]() at (5cm,0){coucou\\%
\tikz\node[text width=3cm,align=center](){\setlength{\baselineskip}{1pt}\tiny These certificates can be used to digitally sign and encrypt email, authenticate%
 and authorize users connecting to websites and secure data transmission over%
 the Internet. Any application that supports the Secure Socket Layer (SSL) can%
 make use of certificates signed by CAcert, as can any application that uses%
 X.509 certificates, e.g. for encryption or code signing and document signatures.};};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting `\tiny` in the text, putting it in option `node font` also sets the `\baselineskip` accordingly:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle,fill=blue!50,align=center]() at (5cm,0){%
  coucou\\
  \tikz\node[text width=3cm,align=center, node font=\tiny]{%
    These certificates can be used to digitally sign and encrypt email,
    authenticate and authorize users connecting to websites and secure data
    transmission over the Internet.  Any application that supports the
    Secure Socket Layer (SSL) can make use of certificates signed by CAcert,
    as can any application that uses X.509 certificates, e.g.  for
    encryption or code signing and document signatures.%
};};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: OK thank you. It is better than my solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to decide font size you can let it `tcolorbox` to do it for you with its `fitting` library.

With a `\tcboxfit` you decide `width` and `height` and the program will adjust  contents text to fit in it.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcboxfit{\boxfit}[4][]{width=#2,height=#3,title=#4,halign=center, #1}

\begin{document}

\boxfit{5cm}{5cm}{coucou}{
    These certificates can be used to digitally sign and encrypt email,
    authenticate and authorize users connecting to websites and secure data
    transmission over the Internet.  Any application that supports the
    Secure Socket Layer (SSL) can make use of certificates signed by CAcert,
    as can any application that uses X.509 certificates, e.g.  for
    encryption or code signing and document signatures.%
}

\boxfit[sharp corners, colback=blue!50, size=fbox]{3cm}{6cm}{coucou}{
    These certificates can be used to digitally sign and encrypt email,
    authenticate and authorize users connecting to websites and secure data
    transmission over the Internet.  Any application that supports the
    Secure Socket Layer (SSL) can make use of certificates signed by CAcert,
    as can any application that uses X.509 certificates, e.g.  for
    encryption or code signing and document signatures.%
}

\boxfit[sharp corners, colback=red!50, size=small, colframe=red!70, halign title=center]{6cm}{3cm}{coucou}{
    These certificates can be used to digitally sign and encrypt email,
    authenticate and authorize users connecting to websites and secure data
    transmission over the Internet.  Any application that supports the
    Secure Socket Layer (SSL) can make use of certificates signed by CAcert,
    as can any application that uses X.509 certificates, e.g.  for
    encryption or code signing and document signatures.%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found one solution using `setspace` package.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle,fill=blue,align=center]() at (5cm,0){coucou\\ \tikz\node[text width=3cm,align=center](){\begin{spacing}{0.5}\tiny These certificates can be used to digitally sign and encrypt email, authenticate and authorize users connecting to websites and secure data transmission over the Internet. Any application that supports the Secure Socket Layer (SSL) can make use of certificates signed by CAcert, as can any application that uses X.509 certificates, e.g. for encryption or code signing and document signatures.\end{spacing}};};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```